# static files shown as uncompressed even when web server has been configured for gzip compression

Tags: nginx, gzip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have hosted my website on Amazon Elastic BeanStalk. It uses nginx as proxy server and has gzip compression enabled. But when I run PageInsights on the site, it reports that many of my static content files need to be gzipped. Why is PageSpeed Insights not recognizing the compression? Is there something extra that needs to be done?

Comment: did you ever figure this out? I have it enabled and it doesnt compress for me either

Comment: No, it is still shown as uncompressed.

Answer (score 5):

I think I actully found the answer

By enabling gzip compression on nginx, you enable it only for text/html (that is nginx default http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_gzip_module.html#gzip_types)

In order to enable it for other types, you have to do it explicitly. In case of beanstalk, create the following file in your project

.ebextensions/gzip.config

and put the code there (make sure you keep the indentation, it is important):

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/gzip.conf:
    content: |
      gzip_types application/json;
```

As you can see, in my case I needed to gzip json files, you are probably having problems with Pagespeed complaining about css and js files, right? As the link above suggests you can use a * wildcard to compress everything, but if not, just list the mime types you need in the config, deploy it, and check PageSpeed Insights again.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Though in my case there must be another problem. I have a "Content-Type: text/html" but it still is not compress. Perhaps I should not use the AWS Console but just directly nginx config to enable gzip. Who knows what the Console does.

Answer (score 0):

Dmitry's answer only works in the case where there is no gzip_types entry in the default config that amazon sets for you. This is now the case and so you will need to write an .ebextensions conf file to overwrite the entire config with a custom one. To do this you need to:

1. Download the default config from one of your instances via SSH. It will be in the folder `/etc/nginx/conf.d` and be called `00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf`
2. Create a new file in your .ebextensions folder called `proxy.conf` that follows this template:

   ```
   files:
     "/etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf":
       mode: "000644"
       owner: root
       group: root
       content: |
           # Paste the contents of the config you downloaded here 
           # at this indentation level

   container_commands:
     00_remove:
       command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
   ```
3. Change the config to have the gzip_types you want.
4. Deploy your application

For reference this is what my working `proxy.conf` file looks like: https://pastebin.com/raw/KGvdsZc4

Word of Caution:
I have been assured it is a common use case to overwrite the entire config this way and while it makes changing the config easier in the future this will break some functionality of the AWS EB Web Tools. Particularly anything that effects the nginx config (static file paths, gzip compression, etc) will not work. In order to make changes you will just have to change the config directly in `proxy.conf`

Answer (score 0):

techwes solution was very helpful and worked great (in my case, allowed me to add application/javascript to the gzip_types), with one modification:  the  file in your .ebextensions folder must be named with a `.config` extension, so it should be `proxy.config`.  (I tried to add a comment to techwes' post but don't have enough rep!)

It should also be noted that if you turn off gzip in your EB environment using the AWS Console (Environment > Configuration > Software Configuration), it will remove the gzip lines from the `00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` file, so you can use a `.config` file to add another `.conf` file without having to replace the entire `00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf` file.